# Expressing type inequality conditions in a simple bound

Tags: scala, shapeless

```
import shapeless._

trait Something[T <: Something[T, R], R] {}
class Test[T <: Something[T, R], R, T1 <: Something[T1, _] <:!< T](t: T, t1: T1) {}
```

but I get:

```
type arguments [T1,?] do not conform to trait Something's type parameter bounds [T <: Something[T,R],R]
```

Which makes sense except I would expect this to work:

```
class Test1[T <: Something[T, R], R, T1 <: Something[T1, R1] <:!< T, R1](t: T, t1: T1)
```

But it's requesting the same bound on `T1 <: Something[T, R]`.

What I want is to say this class takes 4 type arguments, each pair describing a different descendent of `Something[T <: Something[T, R], R]`. Simple put, enforce that `T != T1`.

What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general example

```
import shapeless._
class Foo[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: A =:!= B)
val x = new Foo(1, "hello")
// x: Foo[Int,String] = Foo@4015d0b9

val y = new Foo(1, 2)
// error: ambiguous implicit values:
// both method neqAmbig1 in package shapeless of type [A]=> shapeless.=:!=[A,A]
// and method neqAmbig2 in package shapeless of type [A]=> shapeless.=:!=[A,A]
// match expected type shapeless.=:!=[Int,Int]
//              new Foo(1, 2)
//              ^
```

in your specific case

```
class Test[A, B, T <: Something[T, A], T1 <: Something[T1, B]](t: T, t1: T1)(implicit ev: T =:!= T1)
```

Comment: I've never used it, but, judging from the symbol, I'd say "not a subtype"

Comment: Ok, looking at the source code, I can confirm `<:!<` s definitely an `A` not subtype of `B` operator. https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/d7a8ecc57bec946d04b0814e567bc229d0b69a03/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/package.scala#L46